# How to insert a date in date field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-insert

I'm writing a simple insert query. Here's the table:

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| name   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| course | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sdate  | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| edate  | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here's the query:

```sql
insert into dummy values('Tanzeel', 'SQL Bootcamp', 5/28/2020 12:00 AM, 11/20/2020 12:00 AM);

insert into dummy values('John', 'ReactJS for Beginners', 6/28/2020 12:00 AM, 10/20/2020 12:00 AM);
```

But I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '12:00 AM, 11/20/2020 12:00 AM)' at line 1

Clearly something is wrong with Date format, so I checked this link:

[Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

I tried putting dates in single quotes which the gives this error:

> ERROR: 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '5/28/2020 12:00 AM' for column 'sdate' at row 1

I've also tried these formats:

[image]

Comment: You are using MySql, not SQL Server. The date values must be enclosed in single quotes and have the format 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'

Comment: @forpas, Tried single quotes also. I've updated the question. Plz review.

Comment: You did not try the correct format.

Comment: See i've a screenshot also with all the format that i thought would work.

Comment: @Tanzeel The format you have to use is `YYYY-MM-DD`, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: Because the datatype is `date` you only need to specify the date as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: @Tanzeel as Progman and forpas mention you need to insert any date with format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`. Once inserted correctly, you can use the functions listed in the link you shared to "read" these dates and format that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MySql the format of your dates is `'%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p'`.

So either use `str_to_date()` to convert them:

```
insert into dummy values(
  'Tanzeel', 
  'SQL Bootcamp', 
  str_to_date('5/28/2020 12:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p'), 
  str_to_date('11/20/2020 12:00 AM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p')
);
```

Or insert them with the default format:

```
insert into dummy values(
  'Tanzeel', 
  'SQL Bootcamp', 
  '2020-05-28 00:00:00', 
  '2020-11-20 00:00:00'
);
```

Comment: @Tanzeel both statements work. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fa92473346d10c81cd251d2ba4e11803   and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=22e6d6bc0c722e0c0a98dc722fc84dd8

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't rely on the default date format. Instead, it's usually a better idea to explicitly state it. E.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO dummy
VALUES      ('Tanzeel', 
             'SQL Bootcamp',
             STR_TO_DATE('2020-05-28 12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i'),
             STR_TO_DATE('2020-20-11 12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
            );
```

Comment: `ERROR: 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '2020-05-28 12:00' for function str_to_date`

Comment: @Tanzeel I buggered up the format, sorry about that. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Luuk, No I didn't.

Comment: @Tanzeel what output is returned by `select date(now());` ?

Comment: `+-------------+
 | date(now()) |
 +-------------+
 | 2020-09-19  |
 +-------------+
1 row in set (0.0004 sec)`

Comment: "still same error" is not very much info. Please re-check if you did not make any typing errors.  When you are sure this produces an error, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63966976/edit) you question, and add all the info you have to your question (with examples, and complete error messages copy/pasted!).

Comment: @Mureinik: When inserting a `date` field you should not specify time, otherwise a warnings is shown like "Incorrect date value: '2020-09-19 12:00:00' for column ..." (see: [SHOW WARNINGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html) )

Comment: I've removed the time. But still I'm getting this:
`ERROR: 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: '2020-20-11' for function str_to_date`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a Standard SQL *timestamp literal* which requires 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:Mi:SS' format

```
insert into tab values(
  'Tanzeel', 
  'SQL Bootcamp', 
  timestamp '2020-05-28 00:00:00', 
  timestamp '2020-11-20 00:00:00'
);
```

But if you got a DATE column you don't need to insert a timestamp, use a *date literal*.

```
insert into tab values(
  'Tanzeel', 
  'SQL Bootcamp', 
  date '2020-05-28', 
  date '2020-11-20'
);
```

Comment: This question is already been answered. But thanks a lot. I appreciate your answer. :-)

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63967370/how-to-break-a-date-range-for-each-month