# How to break a date range for each month

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a beginner in SQL. There are many sources on the internet but I'm not able to achieve this. Let's say I have a row like this:

Date format is 'YYYY-MM-DD':

```
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
| name    | course       | sdate      | edate      |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-05-28 | 2019-11-20 |
+---------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

Basically this says *Tanzeel* was enrolled in *SQL Bootcamp* from *May 2019* to *Nov 2019*. (Day/Date doesn't matters here). I want to break down this range like this:

```
+---------+--------------+------------+
| name    | course       | enrollMonth|
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-05    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-06    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-07    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-08    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-09    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-10    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
| Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-11    |
+---------+--------------+------------+
```

What is the correct approach for this. Please help me. My versions are:

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| admin_tls_version        | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| immediate_server_version | 999999                        |
| innodb_version           | 8.0.21                        |
| original_server_version  | 999999                        |
| protocol_version         | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions   |                               |
| tls_version              | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                  | 8.0.21                        |
| version_comment          | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine  | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os       | Win64                         |
| version_compile_zlib     | 1.2.11                        |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: The common solution is a join to a calendar table

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand

Comment: I don't have any calendar table.

Comment: If you don't have a calendar you should create it, it's quite usefull for many queries. For your query you need a simple one like `year-month, start_of_month, end_of_month`, then the join is `on sdate  <= end_of_month and edate >= start_of_month`

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas, Version 8.0.21.0

Comment: @forpas, I've added a version list in question

Comment: @dnoeth, but how do i populate this calendar table. I have other rows also to breakdown in similar fashion. How do i create a generic calender tabel for all rows to be broken down.

Comment: Simply google for "calendar table mysql". Or use Excel, which has lots of datetime functions, it's much easier to calculate Easter in Excel vs SQL :-)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE`:

```
with recursive cte as (
  select name, course, sdate, edate 
  from tablename
  union all
  select name, course, sdate + interval 1 month, edate
  from cte 
  where last_day(sdate) < edate
)
select name, course, date_format(sdate, '%Y-%m') enrollMonth
from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=801582c768bfef4bfa7e7ec389313a29).
Results:

```
> name    | course       | enrollMonth
> :------ | :----------- | :----------
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-05    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-06    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-07    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-08    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-09    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-10    
> Tanzeel | SQL Bootcamp | 2019-11
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain me a little bit.

Comment: A recursive cte is something like a loop in sql. It iterates over the rows. So in your case for the 1 row you have in the table in each loop it adds 1 month: `sdate + interval 1 month` until the `edate` is reached. You can find more about CTEs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Comment: You should be a professor in our college. :-) thanks

Comment: Can you please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64025684/how-to-use-group-by-in-a-query-while-using-variables
I'm stuck.